# page tpl pattern for a page with contextual parameter

Tags: theming

I create a views with contextual filter and it's path is `prodcuts/%`, I know I can create a tpl for views but I need some more, I want to create a `page tpl` for this,( I want do another thing in that page  ),
what is pattern file name for this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write down my answer because maybe this help another guys in future,I found out that there is not related to url parameters,and it work according to current path, then accroding the tpl file name pattern accroding to the pattern ( `page--path.tpl.php`) the answer is 
`page--products.tpl.php` and work for any address  according this pattern `products/%` .